# Strip off leading and trailing vertical bar | from string in Java

Tags: java, regex

I have chunks of text like this:

`|!?:some_text!?:|`

`|!?some_text!?|`

`|?:some_text?:!|`

..

In all cases I want to strip off `|` `?` `!` and `:` (they could not occur  all together, but they are in leading and trailing positions) and get just `some_text`.

I have problems with having `|` treated literally by regex engine in Java when I use following expressions to be compiled in `Pattern` class:

```
^[?:!\|]+
[?:!\|]+$
```

Comment: You do not have to escape the pipe in a character class.

Comment: `^[?:!|]+|[?:!|]+$` should suffice.

Comment: See the [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/sFK9yp)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps, you confuse `|` as an alternation operator (that is unescaped `|` outside a character class) and a literal unescaped pipe `|` inside a character class.

See this [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/sFK9yp):

```
String p = "^[?:!|]+|[?:!|]+$";
System.out.println("|!?:some_text!?:|".replaceAll(p, ""));
System.out.println("|!?some_text!?|".replaceAll(p, ""));
System.out.println("|?:some_text?:!|".replaceAll(p, ""));
```

The regex `^[?:!|]+|[?:!|]+$` has 3 pipes in it: inside a character class (between `[...]`) it is a literal pipe symbol, and outside it, it is an alternation operator.

Answer (score 1):

use this one line

```
String str = "|!?:some_text!?:|";
str = str.replaceAll("[:!|?]", "");
```

I hope it fulfills the criteria :)